# strange flatMap return type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

my problem at its simplest form:

```
object test {
  import scala.language.higherKinds
  sealed trait IO[+F[+_], +A] {
    def flatMap[G[+_] >: F[_], B](f: A => IO[G, B]): IO[G, B]
  }

  trait FileOp[+A]

  val a: IO[FileOp, Int] = null
  val b: IO[FileOp, String] = null
  val c: IO[FileOp, String] = a flatMap (i => b)
}
```

this would give me:

```
type mismatch
found   : test.IO[[+_]test.FileOp[_],String]
required: test.IO[test.FileOp,String]
     val c: IO[FileOp, String] = a flatMap (i => b)
                                   ^
```

I'm expecting (in the flatMap call) both the `F` and `G` equals to `FileOp` and `B` equals to `String` and this is kind of right, except the `[+_]` before and `[_]` after...

can anyone explain why the return type is not what I expected and how can I fix it~?

p.s. this is closer to what I wanted to express with the `trait IO`:

```
  trait ResourceOp[+A]
  trait FileOp[+A] extends ResourceOp[A]
  trait DBOp[+A] extends ResourceOp[A]

  def readFromFile(path: String): IO[FileOp, String] = null
  def writeToDB(s: String): IO[DBOp, Int] = null
  val combinedOp: IO[ResourceOp, String] = readFromFile("/txt") flatMap writeToDB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your type expression `G[+_] >: F[_]`, because of the _'s you are saying "given types A,B `G[A] >: F[B]`" which is not what you mean to say.  For a counter-example, you know that `Seq[String]` is not a supertype of `List[Int]` even though `Seq >: List`. Instead you mean that for any given type `A`, `G[A] >: F[A]`

Note that `def foo[A >: B]` is equivalent to `def foo[A,B](implicit B <:< A)`,

Here is a rearrangement of what you want which is closer to what you are trying to express:

```
object test {
  import scala.language.higherKinds
  sealed trait IO[+F[+_], +A] {
    def flatMap[G[+_], B](f: A => IO[G, B])(implicit ev: <:<[F[A],G[A]]): IO[G, B]
  }

  trait ResourceOp[+A]
  trait FileOp[+A] extends ResourceOp[A]
  trait DBOp[+A] extends ResourceOp[A]

  def readFromFile(path: String): IO[FileOp, String] = null
  def writeToDB(s: String): IO[DBOp, Int] = null

  val combinedOp = readFromFile("/txt").flatMap[ResourceOp,Int](writeToDB)

}
```

The change I have made is to move the G >: F requirement to be the equivalent implicit parameter.  Now, when you compile this you get a better error:

```
foo.scala:5: error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type <:<[F[A],G[A]] of value ev
    def flatMap[G[+_], B](f: A => IO[G, B])(implicit ev: <:<[F[A],G[A]]): IO[G, B]
```

and when we look up the definition of <:< in Predef.scala, we can verify that on of the A's is, in fact, contravariant:

```
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
```

So I don't believe you are going to get away with this unless you are willing to make ResourceOp invariant in its type parameter.  The following will compile:

```
object test {
  import scala.language.higherKinds
  sealed trait IO[+F[_], A] {
    def flatMap[G[_], B](f: A => IO[G, B])(implicit ev: <:<[F[A],G[A]]): IO[G, B]
  }

  trait ResourceOp[A]
  trait FileOp[A] extends ResourceOp[A]
  trait DBOp[A] extends ResourceOp[A]

  def readFromFile(path: String): IO[FileOp, String] = null
  def writeToDB(s: String): IO[DBOp, Int] = null

  val combinedOp = readFromFile("/txt").flatMap[ResourceOp,Int](writeToDB)

}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the problem at `G[A] >: F[B]`, that really helps and I never think of that before~
but I'm not familiar with how that `implicit <:<` works...
is it the same as saying `def flatMap[G[+T] >: F[T], B](f: A => IO[G, B]): IO[G, B]`?